# Question about the tensor algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products

If $V$ is a vector space of finite dimension over $\mathbb{F}$, we define the tensor algebra: $T(V)= \oplus_{k=0}^\infty (\otimes^k V)$, where by convention $\otimes^0 V= \mathbb{F}$. My question is: why do we include $k=0$ in the direct sum? I see no reason for it, we would still have an algebra without it. The only possible reason I can see is if we include $k=0$, then we have a multiplicative identity, but this isn't really necessary as far as I can tell.

I've been studying $T(V)$ in the context of differential geometry, so I see the necessity in including all powers $1 \leq m \leq n$, where $n= \dim(V)$. In order to keep the structure of an algebra, we would also have to keep all $k>n$, although we essentially get rid of this when we mod out by the ideal generated by elements of the form $v \otimes v$ to form the exterior algebra. But for $k=0$, I see no reason to keep it in the first place. Does anyone know of a specific reason for this?

Comment: Most of the time, it's because we _can_. The tensor algebra is defined as the universal associative unital algebra, and that requires the $k=0$ part, but as you've pointed out, there's no strict requirement for it to be there to get an algebra. You can define the non-unital tensor algebra without the $k=0$ part, and this tensor algebra will be universal amongst associative algebras. This is an unnecessary complication most of the time, but there are certain cases (which I am not super familiar with) in which it is more natural. This happens in the study of certain Hopf algebras for example.

Comment: Ah. So the identity element isn't  quite as "unnecessary" as I originally claimed

Comment: It's always nice to keep as much structure as possible. The tensor algebra is valuable precisely because it is universal amongst unital associative algebra, and the most useful algebras tend to have units (and they're easier to study). If you need to study algebras without units, then you use a non-unital tensor algebra. It's essentially the same idea as with free objects. You can make a set into a monoid, a group, a vector space, whatever you like really. But which one you pick depends on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there so that this is an $F$-algebra; you need a ring homomorphism from $F$ to $T(V)$ in order to have this structure, and being an algebra over a field is a useful structural condition. You also just get better theorems if you don't mutilate $T(V)$ or $Sym(V)$ by removing the field!

But I guess you could clarify your question - necessary for what?

From a geometric point of view, it is natural to consider functions as a simple case of tensor fields or differential forms. This is relevant if you are thinking about the various derivatives defined on these algebras, often these are defined on the degree 0 part in the usual way and then extended by some sort of Leibnitz rule. So the constant functions are just a natural part of this ring, and it simplifies things to keep them in it.

If you want to think about $Sym(V^*)$ as the algebraic functions on the affine space $V$, the constant functions are just there - they are the simplest functions!

I can say more about modules over $k[t]$ than I can about modules over $k[t] \setminus k^*$, at least in part because the former are also vector spaces over $k$, and vector spaces are nice.

Comment: I see what you're saying about functions being a natural simple case of tensor fields and this is definitely a good reason to keep it. However, your last example wouldn't exist if you just took  $k>0$, right?

Comment: Yeah that's true. My mistake. @M10687